# Using Inkscape "pdf+latex" pictures: "pdfTex warning: PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group included in a single page"

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, warnings, transparency

When I include multiple pictures produced in Inkscape and saved as `pdf+latex` in one page I get the warning:

```
pdflatex> pdfTex warning: pdflatex.exe (file D:/..... .pdf): PDF inclusion: multiple pdfs with page group included in a single page"
```

I found almost nothing via google.

Has somebody an idea?